# Java JUNIT red bar but won't tell me error?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I don't know whats wrong with my test/project. I don't have a compilation errors but when I test it, its just the red bar and it won't tell me whats wrong. Any suggestions? My code and question are below. Thanks in advance

> If the calculatePrice method of checkout is called with a basket with one book in, it should return the price of that one book.

```
@Test
    public void test_CalculatePrice_ReturnSumOfThePriceOfTwoBooks_BasketMustHaveTwoBooks(){
        //Arrange
        Basket basket1 = new Basket();
        Book book1 = new Book();
        Checkout checkout = new Checkout();
        basket1.addBook(book1);
        basket1.addBook(book1);
        double delta = 0.0;
        double expectedPrice = checkout.calculatePrice();

        //Act
        double actualPrice = checkout.calculatePrice();

        //Assert
        assertEquals(expectedPrice,actualPrice,delta);
```

Checkout class

```
public class Checkout {

    public double calculatePrice(Book book1) {
        return calculatePrice();
    }
```

Comment: "It's just the red bar": Post a screenshot if you don't have a text output. (You almost certainly have a test tree under the red bar.)

Answer (score 0):

What is your calculatePrice() method doing?
In your Checkout class your method

```
 public double calculatePrice(Book book1) {
        return calculatePrice();
 }
```

Is not even using the book1 parameter to calculate the price, I suppose what you mean is

```
public double calculatePrice(Book book1) {
    return book1.calculatePrice();
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. Nevermind. I just forgot @Test in my code